Compress response of server to client, to send special headers App engine
i'm just starting using App Engine, and because i'm using SSE Events i need some special headers such as Keep-alive, but when i tried to deploy i saw it was deleted, reading the documentation i came across this guide saying i can re-add the headers "if the response is compressed by App Engine", i search on how to do this, but i couldnt find any information.
May i have some help with this problem please?
I need some guidance on the topic, if im able to do it or not. And if possible some alternatives

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you're using Google App Engine Standard (GAE Standard), then server sent events will most likely not work because

GAE Standard will wait for all data to be available before sending it back and
According to Google App Engine Documentation

App Engine does not support streaming responses where data is sent in incremental chunks to the client while a request is being processed. All data from your code is collected as described above and sent as a single HTTP response.


GAE Standard also doesn't support sockets (see doc about not supporting sockets).

It also has a timeout that ranges between 1 - 10 minutes (see doc)


You can either try GAE Flex or switch to Cloud Run
